# How do I list files publicly shared by me using google drive API?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

The quickstart code on https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python lists 10 files from my Google Drive.

What should I do so that it lists only the files that I have publicly shared? Is there any parameter for that purpose?

Answer (score 0):

[Files.list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49614238/how-do-i-list-files-publicly-shared-by-me-using-google-drive-api) has a 'q' property where you can filter search results. Following the [Search for Files and Team Drives](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) guide, you can use the 'visibility' filter:

> **visibility**  (string)
>
> **=**, '**!=**' The visibility level of the file.
>
> Valid
> values are **anyoneCanFind**, **anyoneWithLink**, **domainCanFind**,
> **domainWithLink**, and **limited**.